# How do I change the browser used by SSMS when I hit Ctrl+Alt+R

Tags: ssms, microsoft-edge, sql-server-2019

using this ssms:

[image]

If I hit Ctrl+Alt+R to open the web browser in a tab, I get this message:

[image]

However I *do* have MS Edge installed.  What do I need to do so that SSMS can find MS Edge?

Bug report opened: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7f968821-6c8e-ec11-a81b-0022484bfd94

Comment: How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120189/how-do-i-change-the-browser-used-by-ssms-when-i-hit-ctrlaltr/71135808#71135808) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Well, your answer actually does not answer the question of "how".  The issue persists and I have opened a bug report on it

Comment: There's no "how", you just can't change the browser to Edge in SSMS. I've voted to your issue report.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-web-browser?view=sql-server-ver15), SSMS only has IE embedded:

> SQL Server Management Studio hosts a version of Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Unfortunately you can't change the web browser to Edge. You can also refer to [this link](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/09/06/shortcut-using-the-built-in-web-browser-in-sql-server-management-studio/#comment-12138) for more information.

I suggest that you can provide feedback about this issue to SQL team in [this website](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0). They will check the feedbacks and improve the product continuously. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the browser in SSMS, as SSMS is having embedded IE based browser.[Refer to Stack Exchange Post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307496/how-to-change-the-web-browser-used-by-ssms-when-you-hit-ctrlaltr)

Even though you are having this information being displayed at the top, you can still type in the address bar and most of the sites are working fine.

**Working**:

[image]

**Not working:**

[image]